# How to compile several java files which depend on each other?

Tags: java, class, compilation, javac

I have few java files. `Main.java` uses `Picture` class from `Picture.java` file. I want to know how to compile and run Main from command line ?

Here is `Main.java`:

```
package com.company;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    static Picture pic = null; // Picture class ???

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t1, t2;
        String name = "bears.jpg";

        pic = new Picture(name);
        t1 = System.nanoTime();

        pic.new_img = meanFilter(pic.img);

        t2 = System.nanoTime();
        pic.writeImage();
        calculateTime(t1, t2);
    }
```

and `Picture.java`:

```
...
public class Picture {

    public BufferedImage img;
    public BufferedImage new_img;
    ...
```

Comment: Just compile all those classes with a single `javac` call, and the compiler will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both classes are in the same directory use :

```
javac Picture.java Main.java
```

This way the dependent class (`Picture.java`) is compiled first before your `Main.java`

To run it you will need to specify the entire package structure and run it from the `src` directory :

```
java com.company.Main
```

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Main ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. To run it you will need to specify the entire package structure and run it from the `src` directory.

Comment: I'll mark as answered, and upvote. Thanks for your answer. If you can just tell me, if I have some images that I process, where should I put it ? Picture class just takes name of file as string, and all images are inside com\company folder

Comment: Thank you. The convention is for them to be placed under `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the whole package.

Try running this:

```
javac com.company.Picture.java com.company.Main.java
```